# Why does gradle complain about the Android SDK being read-only?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Building an apk in CLI though the gradle wrapper (Android Studio not involved), Gradle seems to complain that the SDK is read-only.

My question is 2-fold, really:

1. Why does it want write acces to the SDK?
2. If it definitely needs write permission, to which part of the SDK?

I don't want to make the SDK world writable (nor even user writable, actually)

```
Exception while marshalling /opt/android-dev/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-15/package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling /opt/android-dev/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-16/package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling /opt/android-dev/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-17/package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling /opt/android-dev/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-18/package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling /opt/android-dev/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-19/package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling /opt/android-dev/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-21/package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling /opt/android-dev/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-22/package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
```

Comment: How do you update it? SDK Manager needs to write on these folders for example

Comment: What specifically are you doing? My Android SDK directory is read-only most of the time (I manually make it read-write when Android Studio mentions that an update is available, then switch it back to read-only afterwards). I do not encounter this message.

Comment: I'm using the gradle wraper to build an apk in CLI, with a separatly managed SDK.
Android Studio is completely out of the picture, here...